# Machine learning of ">"

Tags: machine-learning

Here is what should be a simple problem with the current state of technology:

```
foo = Array[With[{pair = RandomInteger[1000, 2]}, 
   pair -> If[pair[[1]] > pair[[2]], 1, 0]] &, 2000]

p = Predict[foo]
```

Now, this gives me total junk, and giving "RandomForest" or "NeuralNetwork" as method does not give any joy either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't it a task for `Classify`? Then it performs logistic regression with almost perfect test results.

Comment: @swish I am a complete novice at this, so I had no idea these were different...

Comment: The downvote seems uncalled for.